# SQL Query group and get the more recent state

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have this oracle sql table:

```
ID | State | Date
x  |  A    | 18-01-01
x  |  B    | 18-01-02
x  |  C    | 18-01-03
y  |  D    | 18-01-04
y  |  E    | 18-01-05
y  |  F    | 18-01-06
z  |  G    | 18-01-07
z  |  H    | 18-01-08
z  |  I    | NULL
```

I have to write a query that return me the last state for id:

```
ID | State | Date
X  |  C    | 18-01-03
Y  |  F    | 18-01-06
Z  |  I    | NULL
```

How can I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: If an ID has both NULL and non-NULL dates, how should the NULL dates be handled? Do you need to consider the NULL date as the "most recent", or if there are NULL as well as non-NULL dates for the same ID, ignore the NULL dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

```
Select id,state,date
FROM
(
select id,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by id order by date desc) as state,
       date 
from mytable
)a
WHERE state=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

use first_value after sorting date by desc

```
  select distinct id, first_value(state)    over(partition by state order by date desc)  as 
  state,date from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use aggregation using `keep`:

```
select id,
       max(state) keep (dense_rank first order by date desc) as state,
       max(date) as date
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to do it all in a single aggregate query (no subqueries and no analytic functions are needed).

```
select   id
     ,   min(state) keep (dense_rank last order by dt) as state
     ,   max(dt) as dt
from     <your_table>
group by id
order by id  --  if needed
;
```

Oracle keywords like `date` should not be used as column names. I changed that to `dt`.

Comment: `max(dt)` doesn't handle `null` dates per the expected output..i assume the op means if the date is `null` then it should be the latest row.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala - Overall you make a good point. However, I wonder why you assume the op means what you think, or why you believe you know what the expected output is in that case. It's definitely worth asking the OP.